# Java GUI - Elements with Black Background

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am using OSX in MacBook Air and my IDE is Eclipse and I'm compiling my project with Oracle's Java 7.0.

The problem is that when I interact with GUI elements for example Buttons, ComboBox, JTextBox ... their background changes to black. The problem started after I updated my laptop to Yosemite OS. I downgraded OSX to Mavericks again, but the problem persists.

When the JPanel loads and I don't touch the GUI:

[image]

When I touch/interact with the buttons or JTextBox:

[image]

I don't think it's a problem with my code because before upgrading and downgrading OSX it was working OK.

That's all! If you need more information just ask me. THANK YOU!

Comment: What do you get when you compile your code with java 8 compiler? I ask because I had similar problems when using java 7 under OS X 10.9 and above.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons this might happen, Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses